# how to stop redirect to signUp page once in dashboard- reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to restrict the user to prevent back to signup page once moved to dashboard.
created one signup page and dashboard page.
once the user signUp done it should navigate to dashboard and if the user clicks on back button we should block the user to returning back to signup page.

App.js:

```
export const countContext = createContext();
const initialState = {
  basket: [],
};
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_BASKET':
      return {
        ...state,
        basket: [...state.basket, action.item],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
function App() {
  const [basketCount, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <AuthProvider>
          <countContext.Provider
            value={{ countState: basketCount, countDispatch: dispatch }}
          >
            <Routes>
              <Route
                exact
                path='/'
                element={
                  basketCount.length !== 1 ? (
                    <Navigate to='/SignUp' replace='true' />
                  ) : (
                    <Navigate to='/Dashboard' replace='true' />
                  )
                }
              />
              <Route
                exact
                path='/Dashboard'
                element={
                  basketCount.length !== 1 ? (
                    <Navigate to='/SignUp' replace='true' />
                  ) : (
                    <Navigate to='/Dashboard' replace='true' />
                  )
                }
              />
              <Route exact path='/' element={<SignUp />} />
              <Route exact path='/Dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route exact path='/SignUp' element={<SignUp />} />
            </Routes>
          </countContext.Provider>
        </AuthProvider>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

But, even after signUp it is not navigating to the dashboard remaining same in signUp page.

```
function SignUp() {
  const nameRef = useRef();
  const countCountext = useContext(countContext);
  const mobileRef = useRef();
  const otpRef = useRef();
  const auth = getAuth();
  const { signNumber } = useAuth();
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      setError('');
      setLoading(true);
      const code = otpRef.current.value;
      window.confirmationResult
        .confirm(code)
        .then((result) => {
          countCountext.countDispatch({
            type: 'ADD_TO_BASKET',
            item: {
              name: nameRef.current.value,
              mobile: mobileRef.current.value,
            },
          });
          navigate('/Dashboard', { replace: true });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
        });
    } catch {
      setError('Failed to Sign Up');
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }
  function getOtp() {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
      'sign-in-button',
      {
        size: 'invisible',
        callback: (response) => {
          onSignInSubmit();
        },
      },
      auth
    );
  }
  async function onSignInSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getOtp();
    const phoneNumber = '+91' + mobileRef.current.value;
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    await signNumber(auth, phoneNumber, appVerifier);
    setLoading(false);
  }
  const notNull = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.length === 10) {
      console.log(e.target.value.length);
      setVisible(false);
    } else {
      setVisible(true);
      setLoading(true);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className='outer' autoComplete='off'>
      <Card className='center' autoComplete='off'>
        <Card.Body>
          <h2>Sign Up</h2>
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method='POST' autoComplete='off'>
            <div id='sign-in-button'></div>
            {error && <Alert variant='danger'>{error}</Alert>}
            <Form.Group id='name'>
              <Form.Label>Enter Your Name:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                required
                ref={nameRef}
                autoComplete='off'
              ></Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id='mobile-number'>
              <Form.Label>Enter Your Mobile Number:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                autoComplete='off'
                type='number'
                name='mobile'
                required
                ref={mobileRef}
                onChange={(e) => notNull(e)}
              ></Form.Control>
              <br />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button onClick={onSignInSubmit} disabled={visible}>
              Get OTP
            </Button>
            <br />
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label disabled={visible}>Enter Your OTP:</Form.Label>
              <br />
              <Form.Control
                autoComplete='off'
                disabled={visible}
                type='number'
                name='opt'
                required
                ref={otpRef}
              ></Form.Control>
              <br />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button disabled={loading} type='submit'>
              SIGN IN
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <div className='w-100 text-center mt-2'>
        <Link to='/Login'>Doctor Login</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Even after signUp the URL not changing to Dashboard and the page remains same at signUp

This is the output i'm getting.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of your issue, but the `redirect` property should be a boolean value, not a string. In the meantime can you format your code snippets to be more readable?

Comment: But, i think redirect is not there right. In place of Redirect i found that we need to use navigate hook

Comment: Rendering the `Navigate` component, i.e. `<Navigate to='/Dashboard' replace />` as a declarative navigation action is correct when rendering a redirect, whereas the `useNavigate` hook and `navigate` function are appropriate when wanting to issue an imperative navigation action from a callback, i.e. like in a click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are trying to render multiple routes for the same path. In other words, you've some duplicate route paths. It looks like the `"/Dashboard"` route redirects to itself which will certainly cause a render loop.

It looks like you are trying to create some form of route protection based on the `basketCount` array length.

Create a layout route component that takes the `basketCount` as a prop and handles the redirect to the appropriate routes or renders an `Outlet` component for the wrapped routes.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const BasketCheckLayout = ({ basketCount }) => {
  return basketCount === 1
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to='/SignUp' replace />;
};
```

App

Wrap the dashboard route with a layout route rendering the `BasketCheckLayout` component. The `"/"` home path should just redirect user to the dashboard route (*and let the `BasketCheckLayout` component handle redirecting to `"/SignUp"`*).

Rename the `basketCount` state to be more accurate for what it represents. Here I'll just rename it `state`. Pass `state.basket.length` as `basketCount` to the `BasketCheckLayout` component which simply checks the scaler value.

```
function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <AuthProvider>
          <countContext.Provider
            value={{ countState: state, countDispatch: dispatch }}
          >
            <Routes>
              <Route
                path='/'
                element={<Navigate to='/Dashboard' replace />}
              />
              <Route
                element={<BasketCheckLayout basketCount={state.basket.length} />}
              >
                <Route path='/Dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
              </Route>
              <Route path='/SignUp' element={<SignUp />} />
            </Routes>
          </countContext.Provider>
        </AuthProvider>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

Note the ***all*** the `replace` props are truthy/falsey boolean props.

[image: Edit how-to-stop-redirect-to-signup-page-once-in-dashboard-reactjs]

Comment: I tried with the above code. But, the basketCount prop which we are sending from App to BasketCheckLayout. We are getting double values means, in that array we are getting two values both are same. the second value repeated, don't know why it happen like that.

Comment: `const ProctectedRoutes = ({ basketCount }) => {
    console.log(basketCount)
    return basketCount.length === 1 ? <Outlet />:<Navigate to='/SignUp' replace='true'/>
}`

It worked fine after removing the empty array declaration in props in ProctectedRoutes class. But, after clicking the continue Button it is not redirecting to dashboard page. It is still remaining in signup page.

Comment: I understood how the basketCount state is updated. But, my doubt here is, if you see the signup.js component there in the handlesubmit function we have navigate function. once we perform the submit event by clicking the button the handleSubmit function is calling. But, it is not redirecting to the dashboard page.

Comment: @Teja Can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the state update and routing issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: sure @drew, i'm on it

Comment: [link](https://codesandbox.io/live/b6f2070fc29)

@drew, here is the codesandbox link

Comment: @Teja Ok, thanks. It looks like it was a mixup in the `basketCount` state and the nested `basket` array state property. I've updated my answer with a working fork of your codesandbox. Sorry for the mixup.

Comment: @Teja The issue was that `basketCount` in the layout route was the state object and the condition was ***always*** evaluating false and the UI got stuck in a render loop bouncing between the two routes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246005/discussion-between-teja-and-drew-reese).

Comment: Hey @Drewm, But still i'm unable to navigate to the dashboard- [link](https://codesandbox.io/live/b6f2070fc29). In this link i see old code

Comment: @Teja I'm in chat and in your last linked sandbox. The code in that sandbox still has incorrect props.

Comment: Thank you so much @Drew Reese, I have modified the props as you suggested. It worked fine. Every thing worked fine.

Thank you for your advise.